# Layout problem after integrating a slideshow html css

Tags: html, css, layout, slideshow

one page of my website is locking like that:
http://www.pflanzspass.bplaced.net/

Yesterdy I tried to integrate a slideshow:
http://www.pflanzspass.bplaced.net/indextest.php

The slideshow is working, but now there are some new layout problems:

now:
[image]
[image]

before:
[image]
[image]

I don't know why.

This is my new css-Code for the slideshow:

```
  * {box-sizing: border-box}
  /*body {
  font-family: Verdana, sans-serif; 
  margin:0
  }*/
  .mySlides {display: none}
  img {vertical-align: middle;}
  .slideshow-container {
  max-width: 1000px;
  position: relative;
  margin: auto;
  }
  /* Next & previous buttons */
  .prev, .next {
  cursor: pointer;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  width: auto;
  padding: 16px;
  margin-top: -22px;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 18px;
  transition: 0.6s ease;
  border-radius: 0 3px 3px 0;
  user-select: none;
  }
  /* Position the "next button" to the right */
  .next {
  right: 0;
  border-radius: 3px 0 0 3px;
  }
  /* On hover, add a black background color with a little bit see-through */
  .prev:hover, .next:hover {
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
  }
  /* Caption text */
  .text {
  color: #ffffff;
  font-size: 15px;
  padding: 8px 12px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 8px;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  }
  /* Number text (1/3 etc) */
  .numbertext {
  color: #ffffff;
  font-size: 12px;
  padding: 8px 12px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  }
  /* The dots/bullets/indicators */
  .dot {
  cursor: pointer;
  height: 15px;
  width: 15px;
  margin: 0 2px;
  background-color: #999999;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
  transition: background-color 0.6s ease;
  }
  .active, .dot:hover {
  background-color: #111111;
  }
  /* Fading animation */
  .fade {
  -webkit-animation-name: fade;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 1.5s;
  animation-name: fade;
  animation-duration: 1.5s;
  }
  @-webkit-keyframes fade {
  from {opacity: .4} 
  to {opacity: 1}
  }
  @keyframes fade {
  from {opacity: .4} 
  to {opacity: 1}
  }
  /* On smaller screens, decrease text size */
  @media only screen and (max-width: 300px) {
  .prev, .next,.text {font-size: 11px}
  }
```

This is the css-code, already online before added the slide-show css-code:

```
*{
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}
body {
    font-family:Verdana;
    font-size:10px;
}
#wrapper{
    width:1000px;overflow:hidden;
    margin:0 auto 10px auto;background-image: url(./grafics/bg.gif);background-repeat:repeat-y;
}
/*-------------------------------------------------------------------*/
/*                          font-size                                */
/*-------------------------------------------------------------------*/
h1 {
   font-size: 25px;
}
h2 {
   font-size: 19px;
}
h3{
    font-size:18px;
    color:#660033;
}
h4, h5, h6 {
   font-size: 16px;
}
p{
    font-size: 14px;
    margin-right:20px;
}
h2, h3, h4, h5, p{
    margin-bottom:10px;
}
h5{
   
}
/*-------------------------------------------------------------------*/
/*                          links                                    */
/*-------------------------------------------------------------------*/
a:link, a:visited, a:active, a:hover{ 
    text-decoration:none;
    color:#634142;
    font-size:12px;
    font-weight:bold;
}
a:active, a:hover{ 
    text-decoration:underline;
}
/*-------------------------------------------------------------------*/
/*                          header                                   */
/*-------------------------------------------------------------------*/
#header {
    width:968px;
    height:161px;
    margin:0 13px 0 13px;
    border:3px solid #000;
    background-color: #000;
}
#header2{
    width:974px;
    height:65px;
    padding:5px 0 0 0;
    margin:0 13px 0 13px;
    background:#fff;
    clear:both;
}
#logo {
    width:222px;
    margin: 0 0 0 0;
    padding: 0 5px 0 0;
    float: left;
    overflow: hidden;
}
#header-title {
    height: 160px;
    background: transparent url(banner_2.jpg) no-repeat 0 0;
    float:left;
}

#ueberschrift {
    padding:60px 0 0 20px;
    color:#fff;
}
#ueberschrift p{
    font-size:16px;
}
#content-header{
    width:990px;height:60px;
    padding:0 0 20px 10px;
}
#like{
    width:77px;
    margin:5px 30px 0 10px;
    float:left;
}
#kaktus-banner{
    width:468px;
    margin:5px 0 0 129px;
    float:left;
}
#wobinich{
    width:964px;height:16px;
    margin:0 13px 0 13px;
    font-size:12px;
    border-bottom:1px solid #000;
    background:#fff;
    float:left;padding:0 0 0 10px;
    
}
h2.title{
    text-align:center;
    height:40px;
    font-size:30px;
    background: transparent url(./grafics/bg-title1.gif) no-repeat 0px 35px; 
}
h2.title2{
    
    
    height:40px;
    font-size:30px;
    background: transparent url(./grafics/bg-title3.gif) no-repeat 0px 35px; 
}
h2.gb{
    height:30px;
    background: transparent url(./grafics/bg-title3.gif) no-repeat 0px 25px;
}
/*-------------------------------------------------------------------*/
/*                          content                                  */
/*-------------------------------------------------------------------*/


#content {
    width:974px;
    margin:0 13px 0 13px;
    background:#fff;
    float:left;
}
#content p{
    line-height:24px;
}
#links{
    width:185px;
    margin:0 0 0 0;
    float:left;
}
#mitte{
    width:609px; /*609px*/
    padding:10px 10px 0 10px;
    float:left;
}
#mitte_a-z{
    width:873px;
    padding:10px 0 0 20px;
}
#mitte1{
    width:767px;
    padding:10px 10px 0 10px;
    float:left;
}
#rechts{
    width:160px;
    margin:0 0px 10px 0;
    float:right;
}
#film{
    margin:10px 0 10px 182px;
}

#footer{
    width:974px;height:30px;
    
    font-size:12px;
    line-height: 27px;
    text-align:center;
    color:#000;
    border-top:1px solid #000;background:#fff;border-bottom:1px solid #000;background:#fff;
    float:left;
}
#footer a{
    font-weight:normal;
    color:#000;
}
/*-------------------------------------------------------------------*/
/*                          navigation                               */
/*-------------------------------------------------------------------*/
.navtitle{
    margin:0px;
    background:#7fb37f;
    text-align:center;
}
#navigationsleiste{
    margin:0 16px 20px 0;padding:0 0 10px 0;
    width:185px;background:#a5e8a5;
}
#navigationsleiste a{
    display: block;
    height: 20px;
    padding:8px 0 0 19px;
    
    color: #000;
    text-decoration: none;
}
#navigationsleiste a:hover{
    background: transparent url(./grafics/liste.gif) no-repeat 5px 12px;
    
}
#navigationsleiste a.aktiv{
    background: transparent url(./grafics/liste.gif) no-repeat 5px 12px;
    
}
.link{
    /*margin:0 16px -2000px 0;padding-bottom:2000px;*/
    width: 185px;background:#a5e8a5;
}
.link a{
    display: block;
    height: 20px;
    margin:2px;
    padding:10px 0 10px 9px;
    font-size:12px;
}
.link-re{
    /*margin:0 0px -2500px 0;padding:0 0 2500px 0;*/
    width: 160px;background:#a5e8a5;
}
.link-re a{
    display: block;
    height: 20px;
    margin:0px;
    padding:2px 0 0 20px;
    font-size:12px;
    font-weight:bold;
    
}
#zapp{
    width:964px;height:20px;
    margin:0 13px 0 13px;
    font-size:12px;
    background:#fff;
    border-bottom:1px solid #000;
    padding:10px 0 0 10px;
    float:left;
    
}
.up{
    margin:10px 0 10px 0px;
    text-align:right;
 
}
.up a{
    font-weight:bold;
}
.back{
    margin:0 60px 0 0;
    float:left
}
.zurueck{
    float:left;
}
.ist{
    float:left;
    color:#a5a5a5;
    margin-left:30px;
}
.vor{
    margin:0 0 0 30px;
    float:left;
}
/*-------------------------------------------------------------------*/
/*                          listenelemente                           */
/*-------------------------------------------------------------------*/
ul{
    list-style-type:none;
}
li{
  
}
#mitte ul{
    list-style-type:disc;
    margin-left:15px;
}
#mitte li a{
   
}
ol{
    font-size:14px;
    margin:0 0 0 20px;
    line-height:24px;
}
.cb{
    clear:both;
}
img{
   
}
#table{
}
p.hn {
  color: #870B0B;
}

p.se {
  color:#057C11;
}

p.nanl {
  color:#64057C;
}

p.bild {
    float:left;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove height:20px form this style

```
.link a{
    display: block;
    height: 20px;
    margin:2px;
    padding:10px 0 10px 9px;
    font-size:12px;
}
```

[image]

Comment: thank you, that solved one of my two problems

Answer (score 0):

```
* {

    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.link a {
        display: block;
        height: auto;
        margin: 2px;
        padding: 10px 0 10px 9px;
        font-size: 12px;
    }
```

Comment: Sorry what´s the other, I can´t see other different?

Comment: with integration of the slide-show, the black border around logo and banner ist destroyed, you can see at the screenshots. And I don't know why

Comment: Please add css 
* {
 
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

Comment: Code only answers are considered low quality. Without sufficient explaination, your answer is hard to understand.
If the OP can't understand your answer, then he also won't be able to reproduce your possible solution. As such it 
would be worthless to him/her. Please add a sufficient explaination of your possible solution.